# Resizable in Python Ursina Window

Tags: python, resizable, ursina

I want to set the Ursina window resizable to False, just like tkinter.

```
window.resizable(False, False)
```

Comment: The default is non-resizeable (except you can still enter fullscreen), so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work you can't resize the ursina window (never worked for me)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).